# The algorithm for the knapsack problem does not pass all tests

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

Good afternoon! I am starting to learn dynamic programming and trying to "I" problem on CodeForces. [codeforces.com/gym/100135](https://codeforces.com/gym/100135) Problem link: [LINK](https://github.com/nskybytskyi/Codeforces/blob/main/DynamicProgrammingC/statements.pdf)
Here is my code:

```
def read_ints():
return list(map(int, input().split()))

s, n = read_ints()
c = read_ints()

d = [[False for i in range(s + 1)] for j in range(n + 1)]
d[0][0] = True

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(s + 1):
        d[i][j] = d[i - 1][j] or d[i - 1][j - c[i - 1]]

i = s
while not d[n][i]:
    i -= 1

print(i)
```

I use the typical way of solving **knapsack problems**.
But this algorithm fails the fifth test. What could be the problem?